# Search Function with radio button ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with my jquery. I'm not 100% sure why it does not work. so i need some help to find out whats wrong and how to solve it.

This should be used for a search function for searching through the database for arena teams from a game. The code does work fine if i only select value from the search box. But it doesnt work when i use both searchbox and radio buttons

Here is my html code

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="search" name="itemname" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search Arena Team" class="first"><br>
            <label for="two">2v2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="two" class="type" value="2"><br>
            <label for="three">3v3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="three" class="type" value="3"><br>
            <label for="five">5v5</label>
            <input type="radio" name="type" id="five" class="type" value="5"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Search !">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <table id="searchResult">
            <tr class="tablerow">
                <th>Team Name</th>
                <th>Team Rating</th>
                <th>Team Rank</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

And here is my jQuery

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var showResult = function(data) {
                    $('#searchResult td').parent().remove();
                    $.each(data, function(index, info) {
                        $('#searchResult tr:last').after(
                            '<tr class="tablerow">' +
                                '<td>' + info['name'] + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + info['rating']  + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + info['rank'] + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>'
                        );
                    });
                };

                $('#searchbar').on('input', function() {

                    $.get('functions/arenasearch.php', { 
                        name: $(this).val()
                    },
                    showResult).fail(function() {

                    });

                });

                $('.type').on('change', function() {

                    $.get('functions/arenasearch.php', { 
                        type: $(this).val()
                    },

                    showResult).fail(function() {

                    });
                });

            });
```

For some reason i cannot post my php script so i upload it to pastebin
http://pastebin.com/CrCMpVXG

Comment: you need to pass both values currently you are only passing one for each

Comment: And how can i pass both values?

Comment: pfff... putvande got me on time.. I write so much explanations.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned in the comments, you should pass both the values, you can just combine the two values you want to send to your search script in one query. Something like:

```
$('#searchbar').on('input', function () {
    search();
});

$('.type').on('change', function () {
    search();
});

function search() {
    $.get('functions/arenasearch.php', {
        name: $('#searchbar').val(),
        type: $('.type:checked').val()
    }, showResult).fail(function() {

    });
}
```